# Transparent reverse proxying using org.restlet.routing.Redirector

Tags: java, http-headers, reverse-proxy, restlet, restlet-2.0

I am trying to create a transparent reverse proxy using `org.restlet.routing.Redirector`.

For the sake of simplicity let's say all I want to do is to redirect all HTTP requests pointing at

```
http://localhost:80
```

to be dispatched to another unrelated HTTP server:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

I've wrote a simple reverse proxy using Redirector (MODE_SERVER_OUTBOUND mode) and it actually works as expected in the sense that it dispatches requests properly and also handles redirects.

But now let's say that resources at `http://localhost:8080` are protected with Digest authentication mechanism.

Now the problem is that headers in requests and responses when handled by Redirector are removed (from docs `WRT MODE_SERVER_OUTBOUND`):

> Note that in this mode, the headers of HTTP requests, stored in the
>   request's attributes, are removed before dispatching. Also, when a
>   HTTP    response comes back the headers are also removed.

which makes Digest authentication mechanism unusable.

I guess that reverse proxy should return responses as if it was itself the origin.

Is there any way to leave headers intact so that end server (`http://localhost:8080`) and clients could communicate as there is no proxy in between?

Comment: Here is the related discussion in Restlet mailing list: http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=3076621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Arjohn (see related discussion in Restlet [mailing list](http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=3076835)) the solution was found:

> We've updated from restlet 2.1.4 to 2.2.0 now and to our surprise this
>   fixed the Redirector problems. In fact, Redirector works perfectly 
>   out-of-the-box, including the digest authentication. No subclassing 
>   required. So probably this was a bug in 2.1.4 that has been fixed 
>   somewhere in the 2.2 development.